# Why is my delegate method not being called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, delegates, protocols

In this code I'm attempting to pass an array from one tab view to another using protocols. The method itself is a simple get method with one line returning an a mutableArray. Within it's own class it works, within this class it is not even called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myLocationEntityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self delegate] getMyLocationEntityArray]];
}
```

The header file for the class receiving the data:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@protocol CoreDataDelegate;

@interface ListTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSMutableArray *myLocationEntityArray;

    id <CoreDataDelegate> delegate;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)fetchCoreData;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property(nonatomic, assign) id <CoreDataDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myLocationEntityArray;

@end

@protocol CoreDataDelegate

//- (NSMutableArray *) fetchCoreData;
- (NSMutableArray *) getMyLocationEntityArray;

@end
```

The top of the header file sending the data:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, CoreDataDelegate>
```

Comment: Is the delegate already set when `viewDidLoad` is reached? I bet it's nil.

Comment: Where do you assign the delegate? Are you sure self.delegate is not nil when you are asking it for the location entity array?

Comment: How do I set it? I suspected this may have been the problem and tried self.delegate = self but got an error telling me the two types were incompatible.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: "delegate" is not descriptive enough, esp when you have 2 types.  Try "codeDataDelegate" and "locManDelegate" so you don't confuse yourself (or people trying to help you on SO).  Also, in your viewDidLoad, break that nested one line into 3 or 4 lines.  This makes is much easier to read and understand, and also much easier to debug - you can drop an NSLog after any of the sub steps to see what's wrong or nil.

Comment: Just done this. The delegate is indeed null. This is my first time using delegates. What should I be setting it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should change your procotol like this :

```
@protocol CoreDataDelegate

//- (NSMutableArray *) fetchCoreData;
- (void) getMyLocationEntityArray:(NSMutableArray *)entityArray;

@end
```

You set your `MapViewController` to responds to your protocol `CoreDateDelegate`. So, I suppose you alloc your `ListTableViewController` inside the `MapViewController`. If that is the case, you need to do this :

```
// MapViewController.m
...
ListTableViewController *listVC = [[ListTableViewController alloc] init];
listVC.delegate = self;
// display your listVC
...

// Somewhere in your code of MapViewController.m
- (void) getMyLocationEntityArray:(NSMutableArray *)entityArray {
   // do something with entityArray
}
```

*EDIT*

Following your comments, here is a simpler way to do what you want. `NSNotification`. It does not require protocol, and is easier to implement.

```
// In ListTableViewController.m
// In Init or viewDidLoad function


   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(getEntity:) 
                                                 name:@"GetEntity"
                                               object:nil];

- (void)getEntity:(NSNotification *)notif {
   NSArray *entityArray = (NSArray *)[notif object];
   // do something with entityArray
}

// In dealloc or viewDidUnLoad function
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                 name:@"GetEntity"
                                               object:nil];


// In MapViewController.m
// theEntityArray to be defined
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"GetEntity"
                                                         object:theEntityArray 
                                                       userInfo:nil];
```

In few words, when you will post the GetEntity notification in `MapViewController`, it will call undirectly the `-(void)getEntity:` function of `ListTableViewController`

Comment: I've already created an instance of the ListTableViewController within the app delegate and placed it within a tabBarController. Should I apply the listVC.delegate = self within the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method or create a new instance as above?

Comment: Also why do we set the data we want as an argument rather than as our return? I've no doubt your right but I'd like to understand why.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding delegate protocols. The id < CoreDataDelegate>delegate is a pointer to another view controller (or object). If you put listVC.delegate = self within the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, this will mean your AppDelegate will be the location where your procotol functions will be called.

Comment: Does your MapViewController is also created in the app delegate? If that is the case you can do listVC.delegate = mapVC (where mapVC is your MapViewController instance). And so, put your protocol function as I explained in my answer

Comment: I want the MapViewController to send MyLocationEntityArray to the ListViewController. Your code is for that way round isn't it? As I don't see how the getMyLocationEntityArray method can be of any use unless it is written within the ListTableViewController so it can save the entityArray argument.

Comment: urrgh I think I've done everything the wrong way round. I'll get to work switching everything over then applying your code. Thanks

Comment: Please check my updated post, there is a another way to pass data from one view controller to another