# Delegate method not being executed

Tags: objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a superViewcontroller named CenterViewController in which i have implemented UITabBarController *tabVC and the viewcontroller of tabVC are featureViewController, scheduleViewController, feedbackViewController, contactUsViewController.

they are added as :

```
tabVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:featureViewController,scheduleViewController,feedbackViewController,contactUsViewController, nil];
self addChildViewController:tabVC];
[self.view addSubview:tabVC.view];
```

I have to access a function named loadHome which is in CenterViewcontroller from feedbackviewcontroller when the feedback is submitted successfully:

```
-(void) loadHome
{
  [tabVC setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

Searched a lot got one solution to implement protocol delegate the code of which is as follows:

centerviewcontroller.h

```
@protocol CenterViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
 - (void)loadHome;
@end
@interface CenterViewController : UIViewController <LeftPanelViewControllerDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CenterViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

feedbackviewcontroller.h

```
#import "CenterViewController.h"

@interface FeedbackViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
{   
  id<CenterViewControllerDelegate> centerdelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) id<CenterViewControllerDelegate> centerdelegate;
```

when the button on alertview when feedback is successfully submitted is clicked I am able to call the loadHome function of centerviewcontroller:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  NSLog(@"alert view button index %d", buttonIndex);


  switch(buttonIndex)
  {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"alert view button index inside switch %d", buttonIndex);
        [self.centerdelegate loadHome];
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }    
}
```

The [self.centerdelegate loadHome]; is getting executed but it doesn't take me to the function in centerviewcontroller.

No error nothing happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my delegate method not being called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505945/why-is-my-delegate-method-not-being-called)

Comment: I can't see you setting the delegate property anywhere. Also, use `@[featureViewController,scheduleViewController,...]` instead of `[NSArray arrayWithObjects]`

Comment: where should i set delegate property please do let me know as i am new to ios

Answer (score 0):

The reason your delegate method isn't executed is because you didn't set a delegate (aka `self.delegate` is `nil`).

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c) a full explanation on how to use delegates including certain protocols and optimizations.